# Add dynamic route with constraint in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In our `Rails 4.2` app, some `dynamic routes` are stored in a table and is added in `routes.rb` after retrieving from the table. In `routes.rb` it is:

```
  some_routes = find_config_const('some_route')
  eval(some_routes) if some_routes.present?
```

Here is an example of `some_routes`:

```
  member do
    get :event_action
    patch :submit
    patch :stamp
    patch :pay
    get :wf_edit
    patch :wf_edit_result
  end
```

After changing the structure, now we are facing a problem. The problem is that a session variable `session[:token]` is added to `find_config_const` as a search constraint like this:

```
  some_routes = find_config_const('some_route', session[:token])
  eval(some_routes) if some_routes.present?
```

Since `session` is not available in `routes.rb`, so `find_config_const` returns an error with `wrong number of argument`. Basically we need either find a way to pass the value of `session[:token]` into `routes.rb`, or find another way to add the `some_routes` into the routing table. The `token` is unique for one app and may define it as a constant. Any ideas/suggestion about how to do the dynamic routes in our case?

Comment: You don't need to use `eval` for this. And the routes are not evaluated on each page load are they? In either case you could keep the routes and limit access through your controller where you have access to the session.

Comment: Routes probably are not evaluated on each page load. We need to add the `some_routes` dynamically. The difficulty is that we need a token stored in `session` to retrieve the `some_routes` from db table. That's where we are stuck.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you need to add any routes, just limit once that are already there. And you can do that in the controller.

Comment: `dan-klasson` please provide details if you can. Not sure about `just limit once that are already there`. I figured that `some_routes` has to be retrieved in controller and pass it to `routes.rb` somehow. This is as far as I can go now.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic routes? If you tell me what it is you are trying to accomplish I can give you a couple of pointers

Comment: Some routes are stored in database and pulled in when the engine loads. The routes can only be retrieved from database with a session variable.

Comment: I got that part. What I would like to know is why you're doing it.

Comment: It is for customization of workflow. The workflow may be different for customers.